# How to compile and link Qt statically to MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, static

I have the following problem here. I am writing a multiplatform (Linux/Windows) application with Qt.

The problems are with Linux: I compile Qt statically in order to get rid of the Qt libraries (and in order to have one big executable), the following is my configure line:

```
./configure -qt-sql-mysql -static -prefix ~/qt-4.6.3-static -platform linux-g++ -I /usr/include/mysql -opensource -webkit
```

and some more not so important parameters. I use qt 4.6.3 since 4.7 does not support static linking of webkit, and webkit is used for the help system of the application. Now, the application is also using MySql, and I want QT to handle the mysql stuff for now, so I tell him to link it in (qt-sql-mysql). The main problem comes when I am distributing the application:

For now I develop on CentOS 6 and obviously CentOS 6 comes with his own MySQL library (16) and when I move the application to a Linux Mint 13 box which has version 18 of the mysql libs the app does not start anymore, just the following familiar error:

```
./ddm: error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient_r.so.16: cannot open shared object file
```

(and yes, I have installed libmysqlclient-dev)

So now here is my dilemma: I want the application to be available to as many Linux users as possible without the trouble for me to build an install package for each platform separately.

And here is the question: Do you know a way to build Qt so that it links statically to libmysql? I want to get rid of the line:

```
$ ldd ./ddm | grep mysql
    libmysqlclient_r.so.16 => not found
```

from the dynamic dependencies of the app.

Or any other suggestion is welcome as long as I don't need to make separate install packages for all the platforms.

Thanks